# Why doesn't spawned process start

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm having issues using Python's multiprocessing module.  Here is a (Very) simplified version of the issue i'm having trying to use a multiprocessing queue to communicate between the spawned process and the main process:

```
from time import sleep
import multiprocessing as mp

# add number to queue Q every 2 second, then None
def func(Q):
    for i in range(1,11):  
        Q.put(i)
        sleep(2)
    Q.put(None)

# start the process to add numbers
Q = mp.Queue()
P = mp.Process(target=func, args=(Q,))
P.start()

# place some initial values in the queue
for n in range(10,15):
    sleep(0.5)
    Q.put(n)

# wait a bit to let process start
print("waiting...")
sleep(2)

# get everything from the queue up to None
while True:
    n = Q.get()
    if n is None: break
    print(n)
```

The process (func) should be adding items to the queue but it is either not started or is getting stuck somehow.

The output i'm getting is:

```
waiting...
10
11
12
13
14
```

I would expect 1 through 10 to come out somewhere in there and the loop to eventually end (but it doesn't)

What am I missing ?

By the way, I'm doing this on MacOS Monterey (12.6) with Python 3.7. on a Macbook Pro (2.9 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i9)

I also tried a bunch of simpler mutiprocessing examples from the net and none of them seem to work either (but most of them try to print from the child process which is not an issue I want/need to deal with).

**SOLVED**

I finally figured it out.  MacOS only has "spawn" as the default start method from Python 3.8 (so my assumptions were wrong on that).  Also I should have used the `if __name__ == '__main__':` condition in my oversimplified example because spawn actually starts a new interpreter and was executing the process creation code recursively.  Introducing  a delay in the feeding of the 11..14 numbers in the queue made it clearer that this was sufficient to make it work (I initially thought P.join() was the culprit).

Here is the code that works with my simplified example:

```
from time import sleep
import multiprocessing as mp

def func(Q):
    for i in range(1,11):  
        Q.put(i)
        sleep(1)
    Q.put(None)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.set_start_method("spawn")
    
    # start the process to add numbers
    Q = mp.Queue()
    P = mp.Process(target=func, name="child", args=(Q,),daemon=True)
    P.start()    

    # place some initial values in the queue
    for n in range(10,15):
        sleep(0.5)
        Q.put(n)

    # wait a bit to let process start
    print("waiting...")
    sleep(2)

    # get everything from the queue up to None
    while True:
        n = Q.get()
        if n is None: break
        print(n)
```

Comment: You aren't waiting for process P to complete though are you? You need to call P.join() to make sure that P is done before you can print the values in Q.

Comment: You're never calling `join()`, so there's nothing here that's actually waiting for the child process to finish before you start pulling items off the queue. Your code is working exactly as you designed it; to start grabbing items off the queue after 2 seconds (even though it take 2 seconds minimum for the first items to get added to the queue by the child process).

Comment: I don't want to wait for the child process to be complete (that's the point of running it separately).  I'm expecting the main process to get items as they become available from the child process. Is that something that can't be done ?

Comment: "Finally, and that's the key issue I was looking to solve, the processes wouldn't talk to each other until I called P.join()." this is incorrect... Join will wait for the child to complete, but it  has nothing to do with it starting or communicating. your thread is  never started anyway. the code was entirely fixed by adding `if __name__ == "__main__":` because the child no longer crashed on startup, and the main proceses waited forever on `Q.get()` for a response that would never come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code, I get a big fat red warning that says

> RuntimeError:
> An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
> current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.
>
> This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
> child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
> in the main module:
>
> ```
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>    freeze_support()
>    ...
> ```
>
> The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
> is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

Once I implement as the instruction tells me, your code works fine.

I also did a little bit of refactoring to follow some PEP recommendations, just because I can.

```py
from time import sleep
import multiprocessing as mp


def produce(queue: mp.Queue) -> None:
    for i in range(1, 11):
        queue.put(i)
        sleep(2)
    queue.put(None)


def consume(queue: mp.Queue) -> None:
    while True:
        n = queue.get()
        if n is None:
            break
        print(n)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dataexchange = mp.Queue()
    for number in range(10, 15):
        dataexchange.put(number)
    process = mp.Process(target=produce, args=(dataexchange,))
    process.start()
    print("waiting...")
    sleep(2)

    consume(dataexchange)
```

Comment: MacOS uses "spawn" as the default start method (not fork) and I would like to keep it that way so I can run this on Windows as well eventually (Windows only supports spawn).  I copied and pasted you revised code and get the same result (i.e. only the 10..14 numbers print then everything hangs).  I'm also not getting any error messages (using IDLE).

Comment: I changed it to use `ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')` and it still works. Why do all people use IDLE instead of Pycharm? IDLE is such a .... limited ... IDE

Comment: I made a combination of errors, but in the end that `__main__` test was the core issue in my example.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't protect your code from import (necessary when using "spawn" as the start method), so the child process will raise a `RuntimeError`. The thing is that this exception is generated from the Child process, so the main process will continue to wait on responses from a child that has already exited. The error message may not be printed by IDE's that don't correctly redirect STDERR, so you should instead run your code via Terminal instead to make sure you see the error (and correct it as Thomas has done).